# String is not a valid Date time in c#

Tags: c#, string, datetime

When I try to convert the string "25-12-2014 15:35" to a `DateTime`, I get an exception that the string is not a valid `DateTime`.  How do I avoid this exception?

```
String Mydate= col.Get("StartDate");
DateTime startDate = DateTime.ParseExact(MyString, "dd-MM-yyyy", null);
```

Comment: Show your code also. And what is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions like "Why isn't my code working" need to include a minimum, complete, valid example. Please edit your question with details of your code, the behaviour you're getting, and the behaviour you expect.

Comment: @SonerGönül please let me know if u have the solution.

Comment: hi off of my head you need to use tryparse with a CultureInfo, EDIT: didnt see what Soner Gönül posted, use what he said!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to
>   its DateTime equivalent using the specified format and
>   culture-specific format information. **The format of the string
>   representation must match the specified format exactly.**

In your case, they are not. You didn't use any format for your hours and minutes part. Use `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm` format instead.

```
string s = "25-12-2014 15:35";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", null,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt);
}
```

Since you used `null` as a `IFormatProvider`, it uses [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) by default. And if your `CurrentCulture`'s [`TimeSeparator` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.timeseparator.aspx) is not `:`, your parsing operation will fail *even* if your date string and format string have the same format.

In such a case, you can clone your current culture with [`CultureInfo.Clone` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.clone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and set it's `TimeSeparator` property to `:` or you can use [`InvariantCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which has already `:` as a time separator.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to parse it exact:

```
DateTime d = DateTime.ParseExact("25-12-2014 15:35", "dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Or use the right culture (for example Dutch):

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Parse("25-12-2014 15:35", new CultureInfo("nl-NL"));
```

Comment: this code is not working dude. i am getting still same exception.

Comment: Then you should check what is wrong, since this code works fine. Tested it two times. Which of the statements is causing you trouble?